# Convert JSON keys to strings

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to convert the follow json

```
{
    "one": {
        "two": {
            "three": {
                 "superNestedJSONBody": "please, help me",
                 "superNestedJSONBody2Again": "please, help me again"
            }
        }
    },
    "mySuperLongNameString": "is awesome"
}
```

to:

```
{
    "oneTwoThreeSuperNestedJSONBody": "please, help me",
    "mySuperLongNameString": "is awesome",
    "oneTwoThreeSuperNestedJSONBody2Again": "please, help me again"
}
```

How I can do this?

I've tried with this function:

```
function convertJSONToStrings ($obj) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
        !is_string($value) ? $result[$key] = convertJSONToStrings($value) : $result[$key] = $value;;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

But it doesn't work

Thanks!

**UDP**

PHP 5.5.8 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2014 19:34:38)

**UDP[2]**

More clarify

Comment: do you need json output or array?

Comment: @Nouphal.M JSON output will be nice

Comment: I think you need the key as one big string, so instead of $result[$key] you might concatenate $result .=. But beter operate with array and then json encode it. The first key I succeed to build it this way `$obj = json_decode($json, true);

function convertJSONToStrings ($obj) {
 $result = key($obj);
    foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
       if(!is_string($value)) {
     $result .= convertJSONToStrings($obj[$key]);
    }
    }
    return $result;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to should be defined on the type of JSON objects which:
1. Have multiple first-level objects.
2. Multiple nesting levels.
3. No adjacent elements in nested objects, only in first level.
4. Every first level should use the nested elements to generate its key and value.

Here is my solution:

```
<?php
function convertJSONToStrings ($obj, $isfirst = true, $firstlevel = true) {
  if ($isfirst) $obj = json_decode($obj);
  elseif (is_string($obj)) return array('key' => '', val => $obj);

  if ($firstlevel) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
      $s = convertJSONToStrings($val, false, false);
      $result[$key . $s['key']] = $s['val']; 
    }
    return $result;
  } else {
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
      $s = convertJSONToStrings($val, false, false);
      return array('key' => $key . $s['key'], 'val' => $s['val']);
    }
  }
}

?>
```

A quick test:

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "one": {
        "two": {
            "three": {
                 "superNestedJSONBody": "please, help me"
            }
        }
    },
    "over": {
    },
    "mySuperLongNameString": "is awesome"
}';

print_r(convertJSONToStrings($json));

?>
```

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE #1**

Let's support multi-level JSON, this will concatenate the adjacent elements together, and will consider any string on its way to the deepest item.

Do your tests and give me your feedback!

```
function convertJSONToStrings ($obj, $isfirst = true, $firstlevel = true) {
  if ($isfirst) $obj = json_decode($obj);
  elseif (is_string($obj)) return array('key' => '', val => $obj);

  if ($firstlevel) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
      $s = convertJSONToStrings($val, false, false);
      $result[$key . $s['key']] = $s['val']; 
    }
    return $result;
  } else {
    $wholeval = $wholekey = '';
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
      $s = convertJSONToStrings($val, false, false);
      array('key' => $key . $s['key'], 'val' => $s['val']);
      $wholekey .= $key . $s['key'];
      $wholeval .= $s['val'];
    }
    return array('key' => $wholekey, 'val' => $wholeval);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

After your last clarification in the question, here is the code:

```
function convertJSONToStrings ($obj, $isfirst = true, $firstlevel = true) {
  if ($isfirst) $obj = json_decode($obj);
  elseif (is_string($obj)) return array(array('key' => '', val => $obj));

  if ($firstlevel) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
      $s = convertJSONToStrings($val, false, false);
      foreach ($s as $o) {
        $result[$key . $o['key']] = $o['val'];
      } 
    }
    return $result;
  } else {
    $paths = array();
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
      $s = convertJSONToStrings($val, false, false);
      foreach ($s as $o) {
        $paths[] = array('key' => $key . $o['key'], 'val' => $o['val']);
      }
    }
    return $paths;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But with $json = '{
    "one": {
        "two": {
            "three": {
                 "superNestedJSONBody": "please, help me",
     "superNestedJSONBody2": "please, help me again"
            }
        }
    }
}';
it returns only first superNestedBody

Comment: That's why I've written the definition in the beginning of my answer. Because you haven't defined the other cases, you only have put one case which didn't make everything clear to me. So do you want for the sub-levels to get concatenated together? I'll write the solution again with this assumption!

Comment: It will be wonderful if you will write the solution for sub-levels!

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've tested it and it returns: {"onetwothreesuperNestedJSONBodysuperNestedJSONBody2":"please, help meplease, help me again","over":"","mySuperLongNameString":"is awesome"} look the [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3ft-biw)

Comment: And isn't that what you want? Can you elaborate more on what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: +John, the clarification is not logical. can you check it again? it doesn't make any sense!

Comment: You are totally right, there was a small mistake in my question! I've updated it, thank you for understanding!

Comment: Well, your words make my day. Thank you for making me happy! :)

Answer (score -1):

What you need is this function to convert to an array:

```
function json2array($json) {
   if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {$json = stripslashes($json);}
   $json = str_replace(array(":", "{", "[", "}", "]"), array("=>", "array(", "array(", ")", ")"), $json);
   @eval("\$json_array = array({$json});");
   return $json_array;
}
$result = json2array($json);
```

This is if you are using php4.

[EDIT]
If it's php5 :

```
$result = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: It returns an empty array

Comment: I know but this is actually the only way in php4 that I know.

Comment: Well try to take out the @ in front of the eval to see if any error are pushed and check the input provided to the function.

Comment: As I said if you are using php5 DO NOT USE THIS. Use json_decode(). It's more secure.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisTremblay Sorry, but I don't need decode/encode json. I want to convert it from json to another json